# Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i am getting this error when trying to perform the following query:

```
$sql = mysql_query("select c.id as id_car, c.year, c.make, c.model, c.type, c.colour, 
                           (select count(*) from `parts` where `id_car`=c.id and `is_packaged`='yes') as partcount
                           from `cars` as c 
                           where partcount > 0
                           group by c.id
                           order by `id` desc");
```

the problem seems to be the `where partcount > 0`. it seems to be seeing the 0 as a boolean when trying to make the comparison?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to prevent this error : Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in ... on line 11](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3129374/how-to-prevent-this-error-warning-mysql-fetch-assoc-expects-parameter-1-to)

Comment: See if your query is returning some result or not. The returned resource is not what it was meant to be.

Comment: change your query to something 
select c.id as id_car, c.year, c.make, c.model, c.type, c.colour, 
                           (select count(*) from `parts` where `id_car`=c.id and `is_packaged`='yes') as partcount
                           from `cars` as c 
                           group by c.id having partcount > 0
                           order by `id` desc

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Error: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/php-error-mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Warning: mysql_fetch_* expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11674312/warning-mysql-fetch-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-error)

Answer (score 2):

The value of $sql is probably false.  This happens if the query you tried to execute failed to execute, usually due to a syntax error in the SQL.

Generally, you want your query code to look like this:

```
if ($result = mysql_query ('SELECT * FROM foo WHERE bar = \'baz\''))
{
    // resultset processing goes here
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc ($result))
    {
    }
}
else
{
    echo (mysql_error ());
}
```

Comment: depending on your platform, you may want to use `die(mysql_error());` instead.