# how to calulate percentage of the result columns in my mysql database

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a table below that records set responses from users for several different polls; results are stored in the **responce column**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `results` (
  `poll_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `response` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `ip_number` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  KEY `poll_result` (`poll_id`,`poll_answer`)
)
```

Each poll has a **unique Id**; for example a poll asking users to choose between two cars would have **poll_id of 1**    BUT within the **response column** would have the responses for two possible cars e.g range or ford.

```
SELECT poll_answer  FROM `results` WHERE poll_id = 1  AND   poll_answer = 'Range'
```

i now need to draft an SQl query to determine the following;

1. total number and percentage of users, from **poll 1**, who chose Range Rover  as their **favorite car**
2. total and percentage of users, from poll 1 , who chose **ford**.
3. total number of users who responded to poll 1**

i know how to get the total from a column but not how to get two total from the same column (with two different where clauses); and to then calculate the percentage.

```
SELECT Count(responce) FROM `results` WHERE poll_id = 1 AND response = 'range'
```

Comment: Check out the SUM, AVG and COUNT aggregate functions.

Comment: Do you need 1 query for all or need 3 different queries.

Comment: hi Ankit. thanks fo responding. i want to do everything in 1 query. is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just use a simple grouping to give you everything or filter out by adding your where clause if that's what you want.

```
Select poll_id, (Select Count(poll_id) from results where poll_id = r.poll_id group by poll_id) Total_in_Poll, response, count(response) Total_responded, (Count(response) / ((Select Count(poll_id) from results where poll_id = r.poll_id group by poll_id) * 1.0)  * 100.00) Percent_responded
FROM results r
GROUP BY poll_id, response
order by poll_id
```

Comment: hi Christian. thanks for answering. i tried your answer in mysql but got the followng error report:            #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'float) * 100.00) Percent_responded
FROM results
GROUP BY poll_id, response
LIMI' at line 1

Comment: @PaulKendal Can you try the updated? I keep forgetting MySQL doesn't like casting floats

Comment: thanks so much for help so far. i tried what u suggested but it gives me this answer for the percentage: 100.000000. this is obviously wrong. i have 12 entries in the response column, 10 ranges and 2 fords.

Comment: @PaulKendal sorry that's me being a dingbat, try again.

Comment: hey Christian. brilliant. it works in mysqlAdmin. quick question though. when i try to extract the values on my php script i get this message: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given                                                                                                        this how i try to extract it: $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result).

Comment: @PaulKendal Not sure, have a look at this and see if it helps:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3129374/how-to-prevent-this-error-warning-mysql-fetch-assoc-expects-parameter-1-to

Comment: hi Christian, thanks a million for your help. it works now. brilliant advice

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by summing a conditional expression:

```
SELECT count(case poll_answer when 'Range' then 1 end) total_range,
       count(case poll_answer when 'Range' then 1 end) 
             * 100 / count(*)                          perc_range,
       count(case poll_answer when 'Ford' then 1 end)  total_ford,
       count(case poll_answer when 'Ford' then 1 end) 
             * 100 / count(*)                          perc_ford,
       count(*)                                        total_response              
FROM `results` 
WHERE poll_id = 1
```