# PHP error " Undefined variable: mysql_fetch_assoc"

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I'm recieving the above error when I try to run this code, I have tried multiple solutions, using fetch_array too:

```
$conn = mysql_connect('localhost', '-----', '-----','-----') 
or die('Error connecting to mysql');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Subject";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$row=null;
echo "<table>";
while( $row = $mysql_fetch_assoc[$result]){

echo "<tr><td>";
echo $data['SubjectNo'];
echo "</td><td>";
echo $data['SubjectName'];
echo"</td></tr>";
} 
echo "</table";
echo"urnan";

?>
```

Comment: `$mysql_fetch_assoc` !== `mysql_fetch_assoc`....(the `$` makes a difference) - but you shouldn't be using the MySQL extension anyway..... it's 2016 now, not 2006

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Answer (score 5):

There is an error in the line

```
while( $row = $mysql_fetch_assoc[$result]){
```

`mysql_fetch_assoc` is a PHP function, not a variable. So no need to put a `$` sign in front of it.

So it should read

```
while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
```

Answer (score 1):

> Error is clear undefined variable means you are using a variable that
>   not defined anywhere in your code.

**What is the issue in your code?**

You are using `$mysql_fetch_assoc` as a variable that is not defined in your code.

More important, `$mysql_fetch_assoc` it not equal to `mysql_fetch_assoc` as my other mate mentioned in comments.

**Modified Code:**

This should be use as:

```
while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
  // your stuff
}
```

And second issue in you code is these brackets **[]** it should be **()**

**Side Note:**

I suggest you to use `mysqli_*` or `PDO` instead of `mysql_*` extension because its deprecated and not available in **PHP 7.**

**References from PHP Manuals:**

[PHP Data Objects (PDO)](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

[MYSQL Improve Extension (mysqli_*)](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

Comment: The dollar sign was my mistake, I am now receiving the error " mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in (line 19)"

Comment: @Jw13: now if you issue is resolved than chose the best answer and mark as accpeted by click on the left green tick.

Comment: the issue isnt resolved, as I now have a similar problem, do you know a solution to the response " mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in (line 19)"

Comment: @Jw13: this is another issue and new question friend.

Comment: $result = mysql_query($sql); if(!$result) {   echo   mysql_error();   }   check this @Jw13 for errors.

Comment: @Jw13: this will help u for this issue???? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3129374/how-to-prevent-this-error-warning-mysql-fetch-assoc-expects-parameter-1-to